# Is there a better word for the sound of a mechanical "whirr"?

Tags: synonyms, terminology, onomatopoeia

I am struggling to find an adequate word that represents the buzz or whirr of mechanical movement, I want something that feels more technical.

If anyone is familiar with engineering jargon that might help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If there is a technical term, I'd be surprised if it was onomatopoeic.

Comment: just use ***vibration***

Comment: Can you add an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank _____ where this word would appear?

Comment: In a technical context, you'd likely use a more specific term to describe the precise nature of the sound.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for the word whirr but not whirr that has a whirring sound. Hum.

Comment: I would sometimes use "whine".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve certainly heard *hum* used in at least moderately technical contexts.

Collins gives:

[Hum](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hum)

> 1. INTRANSITIVE VERB 
>    If something hums, it makes a low continuous noise.

Comment: Can you cite sources for "hum" being more acceptable than "whirr" in such contexts? Otherwise this is just speculation.

Comment: Whoa, @alphabet, I certainly didn’t say anything about better. I simply offered a term that I have heard in such contexts. There’s nothing speculative about that.

Comment: Sorry if that came across as too harsh; I just don't see why *hum* is better than *whirr.* Of course, if OP finds *hum* acceptable, then you'll have been proven right.

Comment: Apparently I stand corrected. My apologies.

Comment: No harm. No foul, @alphabet